# CURL how to use curl_easy_escape() properly

Tags: curl, encode

I have a url:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaaniPublish/MyPublish/master/8831fbc3-eec7-4caf-91ba-33543fa07456/Test data_v1.0.0.1.pff
```

But the url has a space in last file name, so I used `curl_easy_escape()` to encode the url and I got a weird encoded url:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FHaaniPublish%2FMyPublish%2Fmaster%2F8831fbc3-eec7-4caf-91ba-33543fa07456%2FTest%20data_v1.0.0.1.pff
```

Above weird url did not work with `curl_easy_perform()`.
I got a result message:

```
Error during curl request: Couldn't resolve host name
```

What I expected is a url just encoded the space in last file name likes this.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaaniPublish/MyPublish/master/8831fbc3-eec7-4caf-91ba-33543fa07456/Test%20data_v1.0.0.1.pff
```

Is there a proper way to use `curl_easy_escape`..?
What I thought about is to split the url, encode it, and put the pieces together.
But the given url is just an example and this is too hard for me. Also more complex urls may be given.

Comment: correction, you have a *malformed* url, and you are giving curl_easy_escape() a *malformed* url, and it is still malformed after curl_easy_escape is done with it. curl_easy_escape is not built to repair malformed urls, it only url-encodes strings for url parameters... where did you get the string `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaaniPublish/MyPublish/master/8831fbc3-eec7-4caf-91ba-33543fa07456/Test data_v1.0.0.1.pff` from? looks like a bug earlier in the code accidentally ran curl_easy_unesacpe() on the entire url? there's a bug earlier in your code, find it. (hint: the bug is url-decoding)

Comment: @hanshenrik the url is a link of raw file in my github repository. I don't understand about 'malformed' url. I put the url to edge browser then could download the file.

Comment: @hanshenrik I read your answer in other post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773342/15090122 Now I realize that 'curl_easy_escape' is not a method used to encode entire url, just to encode some words like parameters of url. So I will split a url by slash to each words, encode them, assemble to complete url. Thank you

Comment: sounds perfect yeah :) PS what a lot of people get wrong: most people does `name=encode(val)&` , but the name also needs encoding, the correct encoding is `encode(name)=encode(val)&`  (but a lot of people get that wrong, forgets to encode the name)